# Partial fractions Integration - Distributing Coefficients

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Given the following Integral

$\int \frac{2x^3+ 2x^2+ 2x+ 1}{x^2 (x^2+1)}$

I would expand my fractions like the following

$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}$

When I look at the steps for distributing the coefficients

It shows that A is still distributed to x and B isn't distributed to x or $x^2$

This is how they distributed the coefficients on emathhelp and symbolab

A(x)($x^2$+1)+ B($x^2$+1) + Cx+D($x^2$)

The way I was going to write it was

A($x^2$)($x^2$+1)+ B(x)($x^2$+1) + Cx+D(x)($x^2$)

Why is the former the correct way? What I usually do is match each coefficient with the denominator term that it's missing (like the latter). Why does the A distribute to x but B doesn't distribute to $x^2$?

Edit: Is it because they Solved the expression by multiplying the LCD on both sides of the equation?

Also their solution for the new A values are Ax + A$x^3$. That's the correct way to distribute A(x)($x^2$+1)?

After you distribute to A to x  you take Ax and distribute it to $x^2$+1 ?

Answer (score 1):

<s>So you said that the form is $\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}$. This isn't.</s>

You must note that for every irreducible, quadratic factor in the denominator, there will be a partial fraction in the form of $\frac{Ax+B}{ax^2+bx+c}$. In your case there are 2 of these factors: $x^2$ and $x^2+1$. Just note that there should be any linear denominators.

This should hopefully help.

Multiply both sides  by the denominator of the LHS,  $x^2(x^2+1)$. Make sure you simplify when necessary and you should get the correct form.

Comment: No, this is how it's set up in my answer key so I have no idea why you are saying it's wrong. It's in the solutions table. Also that's not my questions. I'm mainly asking how to distribute the coefficient.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that it isn't the only way to do it. Now I realise that was not the issue.  But what you should be doing is you need to multiply both sides by the denominator of the LHS $x^2(x^2+1)$. So $\frac{A}{x} * x^2(x^2+1)=A(\frac{x^2}{x})*(x^2+1)=A(x)(x^2+1)$. Your method of matching coefficients with the missing term only works when the denominator of the coefficient is conveniently one of the terms in the denominator of the LHS.